# How to plot correlation matrix in R with already derived correlation values between variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, correlation

I have an output table which looks like:

```
Vars Corr  SE
1_2  0.51  0.003
1_3  0.32  0.001
...
49_50 0.23 0.006
```

where correlation values were derived in another software for variables stated in `Vars` (1_2 refers to between Variable 1 and 2). What is the best way to convert this into a format which could display the correlation matrix between all 50 variables?

I'm assuming there needs to be a way to make the diagonals 1 as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer but out of curiosity: What is `SE`? There is no "standard error" of a correlation coefficient (Pearson, Spearman etc.). There are some sources that claim otherwise, [which is incorrect](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226380/derivation-of-the-standard-error-for-pearsons-correlation-coefficient).

Comment: @MauritsEvers To answer your question, the output results from a genetic software which computes genetic correlation. SE refers to the standard error estimated from the ordinary least squares.

Answer (score 0):

So suppose you have the data in a single column, you can restructure and use `corrplot`

```
cordata = data.frame(
  Vars = paste0(rep(1:50, times = 50), "_", 
                rep(1:50, each = 50)),
  Corr = rnorm(n = 50*50, mean = 0, sd = .3)
) %>%
  #for the sake of demonstration return Corrs beyond -1 and 1 to 0.
  mutate(Corr = replace(Corr, Corr > 1 | Corr < -1, 0))

head(cordata)
  Vars         Corr
1  1_1  0.453807195
2  2_1  0.237179163
3  3_1  0.303635874
4  4_1 -0.314318833
5  5_1  0.008682918
6  6_1 -0.067164730

cormat = matrix(cordata$Corr, byrow = TRUE, ncol = 50)
# You can use corrplot::corrplot
corrplot(cormat)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input - is there a way to do this such that i could input the diagonals to be 1's since in the original table there was no correlation between the variable and itself?

Comment: well, yeah, ideally you have an actual correlation matrix. but if not, you can use `diag(my_matrix) <- 1` to insert all `1` on the diagonal

Comment: @MichikoC *"there was no correlation between the variable and itself"* The correlation between a variable and itself is **maximal**, i.e. it is equal to 1. That's the opposite of "no correlation"!

Comment: @MauritsEvers I should clarify: I meant to say the analysis I had conducted did not do any correlation with the variable and itself, so **no** correlation value ("1") was produced in the final output. I was trying to figure out how I could input that into the data restructuring to produce a correlation matrix.